# Two solid cylinders are mathematically similar. The sum of their heights is 1. The sum of their surface areas is 8$\pi$.

Tags: geometry

Two solid cylinders are mathematically similar.  The sum of their heights is 1.  The sum of their surface areas is 8$\pi$.  The sum of their volumes is 2$\pi$.  Find all possibilities for the dimensions of each cylinder.

Comment: How is the dimension of a cylinder defined?

Comment: So we have three polynomial equations in three unknown variables (say $h,r,\lambda$). What is your issue in solving them?

Answer (score 0):

Radius, height (diagonals, etc) are linearly proportional

So if the height are $h_1$ and $h_2$ we have $k = \frac {h_1}{h_2}$ and $h_1 + h_2 = h_1 + kh_1 = 1$.

Area is squarely proportional

So if the surface areas are $S_1$ and $S_2$ we have $k^2 = \frac {S_1}{S_2}$ and $S_1 + S_2 = S_1 + k^2S_1 = 8\pi$.

Volume is cubically proportional.

So if the Volumes are $V_1$ and $V_2$ we have $k^3 = \frac {V_1}{V_2}$ and $V_1 + V_2 = V_1 + k^3V_1 = 2\pi$.

Solve for $k$.  Then solve for $h_1$ (and $h_2$) and then solve for the radii $r_1, r_2$.

====

Further more:

$h_1 + h_2 = 1$

$h_2 = k*h_1$

$r_2 = k*r_1$

$S_1 = h_1*2\pi*r_1 + 2*\pi r_1^2$

$S_2 = h_2*2\pi*r_2 + 2*\pi r_2^2 = k^2S_1$.

$S_2 + S_2 = 8\pi$.

$V_1 = h_1*\pi r_1^2$

$V_2 = h_2*\pi r_2^2 = k^3 V_1$

$V_1 + V_2  = 2\pi$.

====

Further more:

If $h = h_1$ and $r= r_1$ then:

$h_2 = 1-h$

$k= \frac {1-h}h$

$r_2 = \frac {1-h}h*r$

$S_1 = h*2\pi*r + 2*\pi r^2$

$S_2 = (\frac {h}{1-h})^2(h*2\pi*r + 2*\pi r^2)$.

> $S_2 + S_2= \color{blue}{(1 + (\frac {h}{1-h})^2)(h*2\pi*r + 2*\pi r^2) = 8\pi}$.

$V_1 = h*\pi r^2$

$V_2 =(\frac {1-h}h)^3h*\pi r^2$

> $V_1 + V_2  =\color{blue}{(1 +(\frac {1-h}h)^3)h*\pi r^2  =2\pi}$.

Two equations to solve for $h, r$....